# VBA Simple For If Loop not working?

Tags: excel, vba

Not sure what's going on, but I can't get a simple For If loop to be fully functional in VBA. The following code only pastes for the first instance of AH = "Changed", but not the others in the range. Any thoughts?

```
Dim x As Integer ' Defining variables to be used
Dim b As Integer
Dim ClaimsDB As Integer

ClaimsDB = Evaluate("CountA(B18:B28)") 'Counting how many rows in the specified range are empty, in order to only run the loop a specified amount of times

'Copy data that has been marked "changed" in a previous worksheet to a different worksheet

For b = 1 To ClaimsDB 

    If Range("AH" & b + 17).Value = "Changed" Then 'AH(b+17) is marked "Change" if a change has been made - I only want the rows with "Changed" in AH to be copied

        x = Sheets("Change register").Range("B" & b + 17).Value 'Define x as equal to the value in column B, row b+17, for a row with AH = "Changed"

        'Copy row with AH = "Changed" from E:AF
        Sheets("Change register").Range("E" & b + 17).Select 
        Range(Selection, Range("AF" & b + 17)).Select
        Selection.Copy

        'Switch worksheets to product data, and paste the selection in a row corresponding to x+12, starting in column D
        Sheets("Product data").Select
        Sheets("Product data").Cells((x + 12), 4).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    End If

Next b ' Repeat the loop for the next value of b, until ClaimsDB has been reached
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyChangedRows()
    'Integer is stored as Long anyway, so it is better to use Long
    'also i is usually used as iterator variable :)
    Dim x As Long, i As Long, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    'always hold references to your sheets (when using multiple sheeets) in variable to keep code clean
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Change register")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Product data")

    'Copy data that has been marked "changed" in a previous worksheet to a different worksheet
    For i = 18 To 28
        'loop will skip empty cells, as they value will be different from "Changed"
        If ws1.Range("AH" & i).Value = "Changed" Then
            x = ws1.Range("B" & i).Value

            'Copy row with AH = "Changed" from E:AF
            ws1.Range(ws1.Range("E" & i), ws1.Range("AF" & i)).Copy

            'Switch worksheets to product data, and paste the selection in a row corresponding to x+12, starting in column D
            'whole copied range will be pasted starting in specified range
            ws2.Range("D" & x + 12).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Still not working, unfortunately only copying the first row with "Change"

Comment: Just tried changing the for to For b = 1 to 10, and it still didn't work - any suggestions for the body itself? It looks like it's not looping properly around b

Comment: Well.... lot of suggestions... Never ever use `Select` nor `Selection`! Also use `Option Explicit` in VBA code. But without knowing what you want to do, I can't give you any concrete answer.

Comment: Thanks, Michal! I added Option Explicit. Could you suggest a way to write the code not using select/selection? I'm still new to VBA and not sure what some good work-arounds are.

Comment: It's unclear for me what you are trying to do, thus I can't help... your code is messy and can't figure out from it...

Comment: Apologies, I have just added comments into the code!

Comment: @arobNYC I refactored your code a little, try it :) Added also some comments in code. As you can see, no `Select`s nor `Selection`s.